# Remove substring in R using gsub

Tags: r

I have the following string, named ID:

```
ID <- c("SONY (~U$) (#T) - SONY (~U$) (#T)", 
        "KDDI (~U$) (#T) - KDDI (~U$) (#T)", 
        "SOFTBANK (~U$) (#T) - SOFTBANK (~U$) (#T)")
```

The result that I want is:

```
ID <- c("SONY", "KDDI", "SOFTBANK")
```

I want to do this using `gsub`  in `R`, but I have no idea how to do this. Any help or advice is appreciated.

So far, I have only tried:

```
gsub("^ (~U$) (#T) -", "", names_P , fixed = TRUE)
```

Which results in:

```
ID <- c("SONY SONY", "KDDI KDDI", "SOFTBANK SOFTBANK")
```

Comment: Die you want to write: `ID <- c("SONY (~U$) (#T) - SONY (~U$) (#T)", "KDDI (~U$) (#T) - KDDI (~U$) (#T)", "SOFTBANK (~U$) (#T) - SOFTBANK (~U$) (#T))")`? The second and third string seem to be combined unintentionally.
`

Comment: Hi JBGruger, thanks for letting me know. That was indeed unintentional and has been corrected now.

Comment: What have you tried so far, can you give some examples of code / thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you meant is:

```
ID <- c("SONY (~U$) (#T) - SONY (~U$) (#T)", "KDDI (~U$) (#T) - KDDI (~U$) (#T)", "SOFTBANK (~U$) (#T) - SOFTBANK (~U$) (#T))")
```

You can use a backreference here:

```
gsub("(^[[:alpha:]]+).+", "\\1", ID)
#> [1] "SONY"     "KDDI"     "SOFTBANK"
```

`^[[:alpha:]]+` means the first alphabetic sequence of characters in the string. Wrapping it in `()` makes it referenceable. `.+` outside the bracket means everything else. So the string inside the bracket + outside is replaced by only the string inside the bracket.

Check out [this cheatsheet](https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf) for info.

Comment: Hi JBGruber, thank you so much for your time and effort. It did the job. I am unable to upvote your answer, but I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You can accept this as the correct answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
gsub("(\\S+).+", "\\1", ID)
#"SONY"     "KDDI"     "SOFTBANK"
```

\\S matches any non-space
 \\1 returns the first (and only here) captured group (...)

Comment: Thank you, Edward. This also did the job!